# How to access an array used as an object attribute in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, attributes

I have created a class with an array attribute. I have also created an array of objects. I wish to know how can I call access the array elements of a particular object?

The class is:

```
public class node
{
    public int node_num;
    public int total_weight;
    public int[] neighbors;

     node(int num, int weight,int neigh[])
    {
        this.node_num = num;     //node number      
        this.total_weight = weight;   //row total
        this.neighbors=neigh;     //adjacent nodes
    }       
}
```

My main function is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n=5;
    int temp1,temp2;
        int adj_mat[][]= {{0,4,0,0,10},{4,0,6,2,0},{0,6,0,4,0},{0,2,4,0,0},{10,0,0,0,0}};     //populating the weighted adjacency matrix


        int i=0, j=0;
        int n1[]=new int[n];

        cluster cluster1=new cluster();

        node nodes[] = new node[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
             int sum=0,k=0;

                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {                   
                    if(adj_mat[i][j]!=0)
                    {
                        sum= sum+adj_mat[i][j];  
                        n1[k]=j+1;
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n1[k]=0;
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                }
                        nodes[i]=cluster1.new node(i+1,sum,n1);
            }
        int m;
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {   
             System.out.print("\nNeighbor of "+nodes[i].node_num +" is ");
                for(m=0;m<5;m++)
                {
                    System.out.print(nodes[i].neighbors[m]+",");
                }
         }
```

The expected output is:

```
Neighbor of 1 is 0,2,0,0,5,
Neighbor of 2 is 1,0,3,4,0,
Neighbor of 3 is 0,2,0,4,0,
Neighbor of 4 is 0,2,3,0,0,
Neighbor of 5 is 1,0,0,0,0,
```

The current output is:

```
Neighbor of 1 is 1,0,0,0,0,
Neighbor of 2 is 1,0,0,0,0,
Neighbor of 3 is 1,0,0,0,0,
Neighbor of 4 is 1,0,0,0,0,
Neighbor of 5 is 1,0,0,0,0,
```

Comment: Your printing code in the end is OK. They just have invalid values from some algorithm/assignments before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your expected output: the last element is `Neighbor of 5 is 1,0,0,0,0,`

Then have a look at where you create the array: it's outside of the loop.

Hence in your loop where you call `new node(i+1,sum,n1)` `n1` refers to the *same* array for *all* nodes, i.e. you overwrite the elements of `n1` in all iterations and at the end the values are those of the last node.

To fix that move the line `int n1[]=new int[n];` inside the loop where you create the nodes:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  //create a NEW array
  int n1[]=new int[n];

  //calculate n1, yada, yada, yada

  //create a new node with the new array
  nodes[i]=cluster1.new node(i+1,sum,n1);
}
```